# Cleanest way to query polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

**Problem:** I have a working solution, but have a sneaking suspicion that it's probably quite calculation heavy. Would love to hear any more efficient ways to achieve this.

**Goal:** I want to pull a list of *books*, ordered by priority, where the book is EITHER polymorphically associated with *school* or *class*.

- Schools: have many classes, through topics
- Classes: have one school, through topics
- Books: bookable by either classes or schools

Current class view file:

```
<%  @school_class_books.order("priority ASC").each do |book| %>
    <b><a href="<%= book.url %>"><%= book.name %></a></b><br />
    <%= book.long %><br /><br />
<% end %>
```

Current class.rb controller:

```
@school_class_books = Book.all.where(bookable_type: ["School","Class"],
 bookable_id: [@class.school.id,@class.id])
```

Comment: I don't see any heavy calculation here as per your suspicion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before any performance issues are considered, you should know that your code as written will cause bugs by finding Books that should not be found.

For example, if `@school.id` = 10 and `@class.id` = 15, this query will return a book with its bookable fields set to:  `bookable_id` = 15 and `bookable_type` = "School".

That book belongs to a different school!

It may be simpler to do:

`@books = Book.where(bookable: @school).to_a.concat(Book.where(bookable: @class).to_a)`

This is polymorphic syntax sugar for:

`@books = Book.where(bookable_type: @school.class.to_s, bookable_id: @school.id).to_a.concat(Book.where(bookable_type: @class.class.to_s, bookable_id: @class.id).to_a)`

In other words, simply do two lookups and combine the results.

As for performance, using syntax like `where(my_attribute: [value1, value2, value3])` will produce SQL like `WHERE books.my_attribute IN (value1, value2, value3)`.

SQL statements using IN can be inefficient because they make it harder for the database server to use indexes on the `my_attribute` field (in this case `bookable_id`).

Finally, you should consider renaming your `Class` model to `Course` to avoid namespace collisions with Ruby's `class` keyword, or programmer confusion when reading variable names.  Consider the awkwardness of `bookable_type: @class.class.to_s`